# Rust: Trait as a return type

Tags: types, rust, traits

Lets say there's this kind of code:

```
trait A {
  fn something(&self) -> String
}

struct B {
  things: Vec<u64>
}

struct C {
  thing: Box<&dyn A>
}

impl A for B { ... }

fn create_thing() -> B {
  // 
}

impl C {
  pub fn new() {
    let thing = create_thing();
    C { thing }
  }
}
```

My question is what exactly should be the return type of **create_thing** to match with **Box<&dyn A>** or how exactly should the returning value be wrapped to match with **Box<&dyn A>**?

Equivalent C# code would look something like:

```
interface A {}
class B : A {}
class C {
  public A field;
  public C() {
    this.field = new B();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want `Box<&dyn A>` and not `Box<dyn A>`?

Comment: This was a mistake

Answer (score 3):

Find below your code with minor adjustments to get it to compile.

I suspect that `Box<&dyn A>` was not intended since it means that
the *reference itself* is heap-allocated (not the referred to object).
On the other hand, `Box<dyn A>` matches your C# example.

The return type `create_thing()` looks good to me because it
does not assume any particular kind of storage (stack, heap, inside
a vector...) for the returned value.
You just have to `Box` this resulting value in order to provide
it when initialising a `C`.

However, if you want to *hide* the fact that the exact returned
type is `B` in `create_thing()`, you can change it like this
`fn create_thing() -> impl A`.

If you really want to return a dyn trait object, then change
it to `fn create_thing() -> Box<dyn A>` and create the box
here rather than in `C::new()`.

```rust
trait A {
    fn something(&self) -> String;
}

struct B {
    things: Vec<u64>,
}

struct C {
    thing: Box<dyn A>,
}

impl A for B {
    fn something(&self) -> String {
        format!("something on B with {:?}", self.things)
    }
}

fn create_thing() -> B {
    B {
        things: vec![1, 2, 3],
    }
}

impl C {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let thing = Box::new(create_thing());
        Self { thing }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let c = C::new();
    println!("{}", c.thing.something());
}
```